# Sending data from one view controller to another not working

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, swift3, firebase-authentication

I am trying to send some data from one view controller to another. But I can't seem to get this code to work! It should change a label to a variable that was passed to it but it doesn't change anything.

`ViewController.swift`

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "SVCSegue" {
        let controller = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
        if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {
            controller.email = user.email
        }
    }
}
```

`SecondViewController.swift`

```
@IBOutlet weak var usernameLabel: UILabel!

    var email:String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        self.usernameLabel.text = self.email

    }
```

**EDIT** I also have this code AFTER `override func prepare`

```
@IBAction func loginAction(_ sender: Any) {

        if self.emailField.text == "" || self.passwordField.text == "" {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message: "Please put in an email and password.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

            alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: self.emailField.text!, password: self.passwordField.text!, completion: { (user, error) in
                if error == nil {
                    self.emailField.text = ""
                    self.passwordField.text = ""
                } else {
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

                    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

[image: Trigger Segue]

Comment: Check that your segue identifier is `SVCSegue` or something else. Also pass default email in else block may be your `if let` condition is not getting executing

Comment: Set a breakpoint in `prepare(for:)` and step through to see what is happening.

Comment: How are you triggering the segue?

Comment: With a button. See my edit.

Comment: You can't use an action directly from the button; the segue will fire before the IBAction and the login operation. You will need to use `performSegue` to trigger the segue after the login succeeds

Comment: How would I do that

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but depending on when the different lifecycle functions of SecondViewController are called during the seque, viewDidLoad might have been called before the prepare code is executed.

Try to give the email a default value so you can if it's that value that are used. Also, set the email value to something else in the else part in the prepare method to see if it's the if condition that fails.

Comment: Yeah its the `if let user` condition

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func loginAction(_ sender: Any) {

        if self.emailField.text == "" || self.passwordField.text == "" {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message: "Please put in an email and password.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

            alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: self.emailField.text!, password: self.passwordField.text!, completion: { (user, error) in
                if error == nil {
               let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "StoryBoardName", bundle: nil)
    let secVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerIdentifier") as! SecondViewController
                 if let userValue = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {
                        secVC.email = userValue.email!
                    }
       self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secVC, animated: true)
                } else {
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

                    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
                }
            })
        }
    }

I have made change in loginAction() that is navigate to SecondViewController and pass data of user

Try above code , Hope this help you and solved your issue.
```

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work. Was I supposed to remove the `override func prepare` function?